# 0 failed to match payload to <Name-of-notifier> notifier

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apigee

I am trying to send push notifications on an iOS device from the APIGEE console on web. It suddenly started giving me this error: 0 failed to match payload to  notifier

Solutions I have tried without success: 
- deleting and recreating notifier
- deleting and recreating notifier with new .p12 certificate
- deleting and recreating notifier with a different name
- registering from device using a different device push token and checking to see if its device specific

There is 0 information on the Internet about this error code. Hope somebody can help!

Thanks!

Comment: What name did you give the notifier?

Comment: Try giving it the name "apple" without quotes.

Comment: I gave it "applnot" without quotes after your first comment and it seems to be working now. Not sure what the issue was yet as push was working before and suddenly stopped. But thanks for the help. Your tip worked.

Comment: It's usually picky about the name, but the service also could have been down at the time you were trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally with notifiers you should name them according to the platform you're targeting. This is either "android" or "apple".

As we've found, this has solved your current problem, though it may be a red herring anyway if the service wasn't responding at that time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rolling 5 minute cache for notifiers. Did you try again after 5 minutes?